# Revoking Oracle Permissions to multiple users at once

Tags: sql, oracle

We're rationalising our database user permissions and to that end we'd like to revoke all select permissions across all tables in a schema granted to all users (but not a specific role).

With some regular expressions I've tried creating a universal `revoke` for each table giving something like:

> revoke select on TABLE1 from USER1,USER2,USER3...;
>
> revoke select on TABLE2 from USER1,USER2,USER3...;

However as not all users were granted permissions to all tables, this results in the oracle error:

`01927. 00000 -  "cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant"`

Which makes sense but isn't helpful.

---

I also tried using `All_Tab_Privs` to get a list of all tables with the requisite grants to be revoked, and this works, but I can't see how to easily get from this to actually revoking the permissions.

`SELECT * From All_Tab_Privs where grantor = 'GRANTING_USER' and grantee != 'READROLE' and grantee != 'PUBLIC' and grantee != 'SYS';`

Any suggestions for how to do this without spending hours in a spreadsheet? I'm guessing some PL/SQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general pattern for this kind of job is to use an implicit cursor to return the data you want and then to build the DDL and execute them.

```
begin
  for x in (select attribute_1, attribute_2 ... from ... where ...)
  loop
    execute immediate 'REVOKE ...'||x.attribute1||' etc';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

A nice alternative is to build the SQL you want to execute in the SELECT and then just execute that. It's easier to test but the SQL then looks a bit clunky.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I had to add a couple more WHERE clauses to the select to not select the junk (index) tables (with $ signs in their names), and also to only select `PRIVILEGE = 'SELECT'`

Comment: The BIN$ tables? They're in the "recycle bin", having been dropped.

Comment: Oh. They turn up on the `select *...` query I put into my original post. There were some `MDRT_...$` tables too. A couple of REGEXPs removed them. (I'm not a DBA so know nothing of how Oracle deals with rubbish.

Answer (score 4):

```
-- Revoke Privs Granted to Users
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM all_tab_privs WHERE grantee IN ('USER_1', 'USER_2'))
    LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE '||r.privilege||' ON '||r.table_name||' FROM '||r.grantee;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Some PL/SQL and dynamic SQL:

```
begin
    for r in (SELECT * From All_Tab_Privs 
              where grantor = 'GRANTING_USER' 
              and grantee != 'READROLE' 
              and grantee != 'PUBLIC' 
              and grantee != 'SYS')
     loop
        execute immediate 'revoke '||r.privilege||' from '||r.grantee;
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a quite interesting situation on my database. Oracles own [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index-097090.html) still listed the existing grants for each table, although they were gone from the `all_tab_privs` table (a *SELECT* brought no result for the searched *grantees*).

I've fixed that by using the following construct:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT owner, table_name FROM dba_tables WHERE owner IN ('owner1', 'owner2'))
    LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE ALL ON '||r.owner||'.'||r.table_name||' FROM grantee1, grantee2';
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This first selects all owners and table names from each table of certain owners. Then it revokes *all* grants for certain grantees.

The good thing is, that this won't fail if there aren't any grants for one of the listed grantee for one of the selected tables.

Mind that this should be executed from an administrator account, like *system*, so the current user has the right to revoke grants for tables of another user.