# Is it safe to remove data from all_tab_privs and how

Tags: oracle

by using

```
select distinct grantor, table_schema from all_tab_privs where granter = '';
```

I find current user may grant access to another user, which is wrong. So then can I just simply delete those roles `from all_tab_privs`?

Also when I run

```
delete from all_tab_privs where grantor = 'username';
```

I get

```
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
       without the appropriate privilege.
```

So do I need to add some role to current user to finish the deletion?

Comment: [`all_tab_privs`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2098.htm) is a built-in Oracle view and can't be updated. It shows all privileges granted to all users and roles, and it's based on the result of all the `GRANT` and `REVOKE` statements that made (or took away) privileges.

Comment: A couple more things: the error messages says "An attempt was made to change the current username or password without the appropriate privilege." That doesn't seem right. Also, all privileges have a grantor so the query with `where grantor = ''` shouldn't return anything. If you don't understand these things you should be very careful when revoking rights - not everything in `all_tab_privs` is granted to a user, and some rights, when removed, can do a lot of harm.

Comment: @EdGibbs Thanks you. From here(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2099.htm) so seems in this table it either grant sth to a user, or a role? And no need for any condition if query this table?

Comment: Yes, `all_tab_privs` shows all privileges granted to users and roles. You don't have to use conditions when querying the table, but it does tend to have *lots* of rows (hundreds or thousands even in a simple installation) so a condition is generally best.

Comment: @EdGibbs Thumbs up for the great tip !.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot (and should not) ever remove data from any data dictionary table.

If you want to revoke a privilege, you need to use the `REVOKE` command.  Something like

```
REVOKE SELECT ON scott.emp FROM bob
```

if you want to revoke the ability of the user bob to select data from the `emp` table in the `scott` schema.

Comment: can we revoke user bob's privilege from all tables in scott schema, in one query?

Comment: Dreamer, if you want to be able to grant (or revoke) privileges to all tables in the `scott` schema using one command, please look into using [ROLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm). As for the existing grants for `bob`, if they were done with individual `grant privilege on table to bob` statements then they have to be revoked with individual `revoke privilege on table from bob` statements.

Comment: @Dreamer - you can use dynamic SQL to revoke all the granted table privs, similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10551291/266304); but be careful and make sure you know exactly what you're revoking from who.